# Looking for help identifying/translating old book

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I'm looking for help in identifying some general info about a book, such as year, title, author, origin, and any information about the contents.  You can see the book scanned into PDF at one of the following links, about 60MB:

https://goo.gl/G3rlUJ

http://europaio.com/0b69r4gjyj46asvvmmdfgmelmsue

Comment: Beautiful book! On the front page is says: "elisabet von gots gnaden geborn aus koniglichem stam den marck+schweden nor+wegen marg gravin herzogen erichs fraw gros mutter" but I found no infos in google

Comment: Just a quick translation: _Elizabeth by the grace of God born of royal blood Denmark Sweden Norway margravine duke Eric's wife grandmother_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s a handwritten book of advice and instructions for the education of her son Erich II (*Regierungshandbuch*) by [Elisabeth von Brandenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elisabeth_of_Brandenburg,_Duchess_of_Brunswick-Calenberg-G%C3%B6ttingen) from 1545. On the front side is her name

> **ELISABET VON GOTS GNADEN GEBORN AUS KONIGLICHEM STAM DENMARK SCHWEDEN NORWEGEN MARGGRAVIN HERTZOGEN ERICHS FRAW GROSMUTTER** / *Elizabeth by the Grace of God born of Royal Blood · Denmark Sweden Norway · Margravine · Duke Eric's Wife · (a) Grandmother*

and a quote from the bible:

> **MARDOCHEUS GING HIN UND THET ALLES WAS IM ESTHER GEBOTEN HATT · HESTER 4** / *So Mordeachai went his way, and did according to all that Esther had commanded him · Esther 4*

On the back, another name:

> **IOCHIM VON GOTTES GNADEN DER ELTER MARGGRAF ZU BRANDENBUBG HERZOGEN ERICHS HER GROSVATER** / *Jochim by the Grace of God the Elder · Margrave of Brandenburg · Duke Eric's Lord · (a) Grandfather*

together with another quote:

> **GOT SPRACH ZU ABRAHAM ALLES WAS SARA DIR GESAGT HAT DEM VOLGE · GENES 21**
>   / *And God said unto Abraham ... in all that Sarah hath said unto thee, hearken unto her voice · Genesis 21*

The universal theme seems to be women to be obeyed :-)